# How To deposit erc20 tokens into AAVE v3 protocol using solidity and remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, aave

I was trying to deposit some funds from my metamask wallet into AAVE V3 protocol using solidity and remix? plz anyone post the code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Call the deposit function in Aave and send along any user funds
- At some point later call the redeem function to convert funds back.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';

interface IaToken {
    function balanceOf(address _user) external view returns (uint256);
    function redeem(uint256 _amount) external;
}


interface IAaveLendingPool {
    function deposit(address _reserve, uint256 _amount, uint16 _referralCode) external;
}

contract AaveExample {
    IERC20 public dai = IERC20(0xFf795577d9AC8bD7D90Ee22b6C1703490b6512FD);
    IaToken public aToken = IaToken(0x58AD4cB396411B691A9AAb6F74545b2C5217FE6a);
    IAaveLendingPool public aaveLendingPool = IAaveLendingPool(0x580D4Fdc4BF8f9b5ae2fb9225D584fED4AD5375c);
    
    mapping(address => uint256) public userDepositedDai;
    
    constructor() public {
        dai.approve(address(aaveLendingPool), type(uint256).max);
    }
    
    function userDepositDai(uint256 _amountInDai) external {
        userDepositedDai[msg.sender] = _amountInDai;
        require(dai.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountInDai), "DAI Transfer failed!");
        aaveLendingPool.deposit(address(dai), _amountInDai, 0);
    }
    
    function userWithdrawDai(uint256 _amountInDai) external {
        require(userDepositedDai[msg.sender] >= _amountInDai, "You cannot withdraw more than deposited!");

        aToken.redeem(_amountInDai);
        require(dai.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _amountInDai), "DAI Transfer failed!");
        
        userDepositedDai[msg.sender] = userDepositedDai[msg.sender] - _amountInDai;
    }
}
```